# Transferring a character mesh texture to duplicate mesh

Tags: texturing

I will try to make this as simple to understand as possible. I have made an animation for a character (the one in grey) and would like for it to have the texture as the one in the t-pose. unfortunately I am using a animator that renders characters without textures. I am unsure how to go about this, any help would be very appreciated.

[image: copying texture]

Comment: If you mean that it is the exact same character you could transfer the UVs and copy the material(s) but we lack informations here

Comment: ah yes you gave me the necessary information to figure it out thank you! i did not know what to research was all.

Comment: Do you mean that you just needed to do a Ctrl L > Copy UV Maps?